# How can i get the profile photo of the pages user liked, through Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I can get user likes and then page information easily using

```
array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'relative_url'  => '/'.$user.'/likes','name' => 'user-likes'
     ),
array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'relative_url'  => '?ids={result=user-likes:$.data.*.id}'
     ),
```

but i don't get a link for the profile pic of Page in returned array.
I'm using following permissions:

```
friends_birthday, friends_education_history, read_stream, read_friendlists,
user_birthday, user_education_history, user_likes, user_work_history
```

and as given in Page API there is no special permission required to get Page picture.

Answer (score 0):

The likes you're getting are only contain some of the data. What's behind your results are pages. On each 'like' record you have an id field, indicating the page id. You then need to use this id to get the picture. For example, for cover picture you do:

```
<facebook-api-url>/<page-id>?fields=cover
```

This will return something like:

```
{
"cover": {
"cover_id": 532177873290169, 
"source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/s720x720/390184_532120873490169_756865062_n.jpg", 
"offset_y": 57, 
"offset_x": 0
}, 
"id": "531671606872729"
}
```

The 'source' field is, of course, the url you need for the picture itself

Comment: I'm already getting the cover src in above array, I need the picture, and the method u told would be too long if a user has 1000 likes even.

Comment: And the query 'relative_url'  => '?ids={result=user-likes:$.data.*.id}', is for getting page data only.